# Javascript Add Event Listener for change in Audio Volume

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save the volume of a playing music file in a cookie so when the page is reloaded, the volume the user chose last is maintained, rather than turning up super loud or whatever.

Here's my test code for the eventlistener:

`var myAudio = document.getElementById("audio1");`

`myAudio.addEventListener('change',alert("Audio Volume Changed"),true};`

However, it does not respond when I change the volume. I've searched and despite it being something I think is pretty practical, there's no information on it.

Comment: 1. `addEventListener`, not `addEventListner` 2. Pass a function as the second argument; that code just calls `alert()`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that typo. Anyway, I changed it to `myAudio.addEventListener('change',function () {alert("Audio Volume Changed");},true};` and nothing happens when I change the volume.

Comment: I went ahead an edited the original, since that doesn't seem to be the real problem. I'm guessing it doesn't send a value on the volume change? That doesn't make sense since the audio element has a volume attribute... so, I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the "volumechange" event.

```
var audio = document.getElementById('sample');

audio.addEventListener('volumechange', function() {
    console.log('changed.', arguments);
}, false);
```

I'm using the bubble phase(as opposed to capture) in this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/426E6/

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#event-definitions

Comment: Awesome. That works perfectly. Also, the reference is great. I'm going to bookmark it. The fiddle adds to the clarity.